# Batch script - replace string for another string from received from variable

Tags: string, batch-file

I have this batch script which has the objective of retrieving a URL from an input, save it to a variable. Then this URL should have a part of it, a 3-4 letters string replaced by another string which is inside a list in a file (lista.txt). Then, the script should open the Chrome browser and one tab for each new URL generated by the string replacement.
I understand there are several other ways to do that, but I intend to keep using the batch file and check where my mistake is. The script seem to be working until I get to the point where the string replacement by another string coming from a variable.
This is the script:

```
@echo off
set BROWSER=chrome.exe
set /p URL=Type the URL:
echo.
for /f %%i in (Lista.txt) do (
    set URL=%%URL:%IBOV%=%i%%
    echo %URL%
    START %BROWSER% -new-tab "%URL%"
)
Pause
```

contents of lista.txt:

```
IBOV
GNDI3
USIM5
OIBR3
MEAL3
ETER3
COGN3
TASA4
BBDC4
ITUB4
SUZB3
VALE3
PETR4
RAIL3
```

Comment: There is a `%`-sign too few in front of `%i` in `set URL=%%URL:%IBOV%=%%i%%`, which must then be preceded by `call`. Do you want to replace the value of variable `%IBOV%` or the literal string `IBOV`? if the latter, remove the `%`-signs around it!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like classical [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) problem. Though I don't have preset the IBOV variable that you are using ,neither the content of Lista.txt I would suggest that this might help you:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set BROWSER=chrome.exe
set /p URL=Type the URL:
echo.
for /f %%i in (Lista.txt) do (
    set URL=!URL:IBOV=%%i!
    echo !URL!
    START %BROWSER% -new-tab "!URL!"
)
Pause
```

Also you are accessing the `%%i` token in a wrong way.

Is there really an `IBOV` variable set before the script starts? You might need splitting or substring substitution.

Comment: When i am prompted to input the URL, then i should input something with IBOV inside the text, for example: www.ibov.com or www.test.com/ibov. So the objective is, to stripe ibov and put each of those strings of lista.txt. For example, www.ibov.com should be replaced by www.gndi3.com.

Answer (score 0):

```
CALL set "URL=%%URL:%IBOV%=%%i%%"
CALL    echo %%URL%%
CALL START "" %BROWSER% -new-tab "%%URL%%"
```

Please search SO for "delayed expansion" for an explanation. The "problem" has been described hundreds of times. The syntax shown should cure the `echo`. Not so sure about the `start` but reading up on `delayed expansion` should provide pointers.

Comment: Sorry, but it didnt work. The contents of the list are not replacing the string correctly

Comment: This is the code:
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set BROWSER=chrome.exe
set /p URL=Digite a URL do dia:
echo.

for /f %%i in (Lista.txt) do (
 echo %%i
 call set "URL=%%URL:%ibov%=%%i%%"
 call echo %%URL%%
)

Comment: this is the response:
C:\Blaster\Programing>Bolsa3.bat
Digite a URL do dia:www.ibov.com

IBOV
=IBOV%" was unexpected at this time.
www.ibov.com
GNDI3
=GNDI3%" was unexpected at this time.
www.ibov.com
USIM5
=USIM5%" was unexpected at this time.
www.ibov.com
OIBR3
=OIBR3%" was unexpected at this time.
www.ibov.com
MEAL3
=MEAL3%" was unexpected at this time.
www.ibov.com
ETER3
=ETER3%" was unexpected at this time.
www.ibov.com
COGN3
=COGN3%" was unexpected at this time.
www.ibov.com
TASA4
=TASA4%" was unexpected at this time.
www.ibov.com

Comment: Remember the requested input should always be answered by something containing the word ibov inside, like: www.ibov.com or www.uol.com/ibov

Comment: if i issue www.ibov.com when prompted, the results are always www.ibov.com when i ask to echo the URL variable